# How to install ZendRest module in zf2?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, composer-php

I would like to install the [ZF2 ZendRest module](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendRest).

How to install it?

When I'm doing

```
php .\composer.phar install
```

in \vendor\zendrest. I get:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information 
Installing dependencies 
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
- The requested package zendframework/zend-http 1.0.0 could not be found.
  Problem 2
- The requested package zendframework/zend-uri 1.0.0 could not be found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-    stability setting
   see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.
```

Where should I put the ZendRest folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your `composer.json` file?

Comment: I used the composer.json given here: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendRest/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: That's not how composer works! You need to create your own `composer.json` and add a dependency to `zendframework/zendrest`.

Comment: Yes, but what I put in it? and where should I put it? I have already the composer.json of Zend Framework in my trunk folder.

Answer (score 2):

There is no stable version for the ZendRest dependencies: zend-http and zend-uri (see the `show` output below for the existing versions). **Composer** relies on stable packages *by default*. That's why you can't install this package.

```
$ composer show zendframework/zend-http
name     : zendframework/zend-http
descrip. : provides an easy interface for preforming Hyper-Text Transfer Protocol (HTTP) requests
keywords : zf2, http
versions : 2.0.0rc4, 2.0.0rc3, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0-rc1, 2.0.0-beta5, 2.0.0-beta4
type     : library
...
```

You should change the `minimum-stability` to `dev` in your project:

```
{
    "require": {
        // ...
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

**Edit:** the following `composer.json` works for instance. This is what you should have in your own project (maybe with more dependencies):

```
{
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zend-rest": "*" 
    },  
    "repositories": [
        {   
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
        }   
    ],  
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: Good answer, there is a typo though. It should be `"zendframework/zendrest"` in `composer.json`, without the hyphen.